# Drawing text inverting the existing colour

Tags: c#, gdi+, objectlistview

I think it is fairly common to display inverted percentage on a progress bar. See examples below.
[image]
[image]

I am using a library called [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) by Phillip Piper, and it has [BarRenderer](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/ownerDraw.html#owner-draw-label). It is good except that it does not have percentage on the bar. So, I decided to draw percentage on top of it.

```
    class ProgressRender:BarRenderer
    {
        public override bool RenderSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e,
            Graphics g, Rectangle cellBounds, object model)
        {
            base.RenderSubItem(e, g, cellBounds, model);
            Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 8f);
            StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
            format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            g.DrawString("50%", f, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), cellBounds, format);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The problem is, as you can see, the text colour is fixed to `Color.Black`. Is there a way to make the colour of the text the invert of the colour below?

[image]

If I cannot simply draw "inverted text" on an existing bar, I can inherit `BaseRenderer` instead of `BarRender`, and draw the bar myself. I have implemented the following code using [the "cheating" described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583263/draw-text-on-a-net-control-with-negative-color-of-the-background-blend), though I am not sure if this is the best way. I have attached it, in case people with the same problem read this question in the future.

```
class ProgressRender:BaseRenderer
{
    public override bool RenderSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e,
        Graphics g, Rectangle cellBounds, object model)
    {
        Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 8f);
        StringFormat format =
            new StringFormat
            {
                FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap,
                Trimming = StringTrimming.None
            };
        float value = 20.0f;
        var valueString = $"{value:0.0}%";
        var backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        var barBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.MidnightBlue);

        //painting the black part of the text first
        var stringSize = g.MeasureString(valueString, f);
        var stringX = cellBounds.X + (cellBounds.Width - stringSize.Width) / 2;
        var stringY = cellBounds.Y + (cellBounds.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2;
        g.DrawString(valueString, f, barBrush, stringX, stringY);

        //painting the progress rectangle(it would cover the part to be hidden)
        var barWidth = cellBounds.Width * value / 100; 
        var barRect = new RectangleF(cellBounds.X, cellBounds.Y, barWidth, cellBounds.Height);
        g.FillRectangle(barBrush, barRect);

        //painting the white text over the progress rectangle only(clipping it)
        if (barRect.Right >= stringX)
        {
            var clippedRect = new RectangleF(stringX, stringY, barRect.Right-stringX, stringSize.Height);
            g.DrawString(valueString, f, backgroundBrush, clippedRect, format);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5167867/4934172). It's about WPF but it might help you.